# PHP form does not check other inputs

Tags: php, forms

I have made a contact form, however the PHP only checks for 'message' and if thats filled out all other checks are ignored. If its not filled out all other checks work as well.
Can someone please help me fix my code? Thanks.

```
<?php
$fullName = $customerEmail =  $message = '';
$errors = array('fullName' => '', 'customerEmail' => '', 'message' => '');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $myEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $timeStamp = date("dd/M/YY HH:i:s");
    $body = "";

    $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
    $customerEmail = $_POST['customerEmail'];
    $chosenSubject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body .= "From: " . $fullName . " at $timeStamp" . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Email: " . $customerEmail . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Message: " . $message . "\r\n";

    if (empty($fullName)) {
        $errors['fullName'] = "Full name is required. <br>";
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z' ]+)$/", $fullName)) {
            $errors['fullName'] = "Your name must be a valid name.";
        }
        
    }

    if (empty($customerEmail)) {
        $errors['customerEmail'] = "An email is required. <br>";
    } else {
        if (!filter_var($customerEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['customerEmail'] = "Email must be a valid email address.";
        }
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors['message'] = "A message is required.";
    } 
    
    else {
        mail($myEmail, $chosenSubject, $body);
        header("Location: public/mail_sent.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure name is added correctly for other fields also, Or show me the form also in your question

Comment: Ah actually fixed it now, by changing the last else to if and checking if neither of the fields is empty. and only if all are filled properly it will send a message.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last else was changed to an IF check with all the fields, and only if none of them is empty it gets sent.

```
<?php
$fullName = $customerEmail =  $message = '';
$errors = array('fullName' => '', 'customerEmail' => '', 'message' => '');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $myEmail = "danysko5@gmail.com";
    $timeStamp = date("dd/M/YY HH:i:s");
    $body = "";

    $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
    $customerEmail = $_POST['customerEmail'];
    $chosenSubject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body .= "From: " . $fullName . " at $timeStamp" . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Email: " . $customerEmail . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Message: " . $message . "\r\n";

    if (empty($fullName)) {
        $errors['fullName'] = "Full name is required. <br>";
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z' ]+)$/", $fullName)) {
            $errors['fullName'] = "Your name must be a valid name.";
        }
        
    }

    if (empty($customerEmail)) {
        $errors['customerEmail'] = "An email is required. <br>";
    } else {
        if (!filter_var($customerEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['customerEmail'] = "Email must be a valid email address.";
        }
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors['message'] = "A message is required.";
    } 
    
    if(!empty($fullName) && !empty($customerEmail) && !empty($message)) {
        mail($myEmail, $chosenSubject, $body);
        header("Location: public/mail_sent.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last else should be changed to IF, checking if any of the fields is not empty then sends the message.

if(!empty($fullName) && !empty($customerEmail) && !empty($message)) {

```
    mail($myEmail, $chosenSubject, $body);

    header("Location: public/mail_sent.php");
}
```